# websocket выключается из-за простоя PHP

Tags: php, javascript, yii2, websocket

Возникли проблемы с веб-сокетом. Работает отлично, все супер, но если сокетом никто не пользуется больше 1 минуты, он выключается. Спустя минуту простоя я получаю "CloseEvent" c кодом "1000" на любой запрос. Когда подключен хотя бы один пользователь проблема решается пинг-понгом, но когда нет ни одного пользователя сокет висит без дела. Вроде уже указал все конфигурации связанные с timeout-ом, но не помогло.

Сокет реализован с помощью библиотеки: https://github.com/pmill/php-chat

Проверял на Open Server. Используется Apache в связке с Nginx.

Comment: Это может зависеть от конфигураций твоего сервера. Их бы тоже надо глянуть.

Comment: @CoonJs Добавил конфигурации apache и nginx

Comment: Причем тут Апач? Как запускаете ws - из командной строки, как в доке `php example/server.php`?

Comment: @TotalPusher Да, запускаю как в `php example/server.php`, иначе он бы не работал. Я же написал что все хорошо, он работает, но выключается когда им перестают пользоваться.

Comment: Покажите конфиг Nginx, где используется upstream websocket

Comment: Добавьте `proxy_read_timeout 86400;` в `location /websocket`, перезагрузите Nginx и смотрите

Comment: @TotalPusher Спасибо, сейчас проверю.

Comment: @TotalPusher К сожалению не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кто бы мог подумать что проблема будет в конфигах MySQL.

Спустя минуту бездействия база автоматически прерывает соединение с ней, а у меня при любом запросе происходила проверка прав пользователя.

Для решения проблемы в `mysql.ini` нужно установить свойство `wait_timeout` в секундах сколько вам необходимо, у меня стояло по умолчанию `60`.

Так же прошу заметить что есть вариант "Б", если его таковым можно назвать.

Для обхода проблемы можно воспользоваться "Supervisor", он в таких случаях решает следствие, а не причину.

Он автоматически запускает или перезапускает сервер когда тот упал или недоступен. Для примера можно воспользоваться [этим](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2015/supervisor-plus-php/) туториалом для установки и настройки Supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 способа решения этой проблемы:
1) Чтобы сервер пинговал каждые 30сек (любой интервал, меньше 1 минуты)
2) Реализовать функцию `reconnect` на клиенте, в случае обрыва соединения или `reconnect` по интервалу.

Вот примерная реализация `reconnect`. Ты так же можешь использовать другие библиотеки, которые делают `reconnect` под капотом.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');

function WebSocketClient(){
 this.number = 0; // Message number
 this.autoReconnectInterval = 5*1000; // ms
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.open = function(url){
 this.url = url;
 this.instance = new WebSocket(this.url);
 this.instance.on('open',()=>{
  this.onopen();
 });
 this.instance.on('message',(data,flags)=>{
  this.number ++;
  this.onmessage(data,flags,this.number);
 });
 this.instance.on('close',(e)=>{
  switch (e.code){
  case 1000: // CLOSE_NORMAL
   console.log("WebSocket: closed");
   break;
  default: // Abnormal closure
   this.reconnect(e);
   break;
  }
  this.onclose(e);
 });
 this.instance.on('error',(e)=>{
  switch (e.code){
  case 'ECONNREFUSED':
   this.reconnect(e);
   break;
  default:
   this.onerror(e);
   break;
  }
 });
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.send = function(data,option){
 try{
  this.instance.send(data,option);
 }catch (e){
  this.instance.emit('error',e);
 }
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.reconnect = function(e){
 console.log(`WebSocketClient: retry in ${this.autoReconnectInterval}ms`,e);
        this.instance.removeAllListeners();
 var that = this;
 setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("WebSocketClient: reconnecting...");
  that.open(that.url);
 },this.autoReconnectInterval);
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.onopen = function(e){ console.log("WebSocketClient: open",arguments); }
WebSocketClient.prototype.onmessage = function(data,flags,number){ console.log("WebSocketClient: message",arguments); }
WebSocketClient.prototype.onerror = function(e){ console.log("WebSocketClient: error",arguments); }
WebSocketClient.prototype.onclose = function(e){ console.log("WebSocketClient: closed",arguments); }

var wsc = new WebSocketClient();
wsc.open('wss://localhost:8080/');
wsc.onopen = function(e){
 console.log("WebSocketClient connected:",e);
 this.send("Hello World !");
}
wsc.onmessage = function(data,flags,number){
 console.log(`WebSocketClient message #${number}: `,data);
}
```

Comment: По поводу второго варианта. Я уже использую [эту](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket) библиотеку для автоматического реконнекта, но это не решает задачу. Я так понимаю порт сам выключается из-за "неиспользования". И попытка реконнекта так же выдает "CloseEvent" с кодом "1000".

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста по поводу первого варианта. Вы предлагаете командой "ping" пинговать сайт каждые N секунд? Потому что этот вариант к сожалению тоже не сработал. Я повесил крон задачу с такой командой, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: А какую библиотеку для WS ты используешь на BE?

Comment: В библиотеке какую я указал есть минимальные рабочие примеры, оттуда я все брал.